# iOS - is it possible to play RBGA videos?

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

I had no luck getting h264 videos with RGBA pixels to work on iOS (tested on iOS 10.2) Is it possible? The Apple docs doesn't say much about it: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html

I don't have much interesting code to share since it's just that the AVPlayer doesn't display videos with RGBA pixels.

Comment: can you add some code showing your attempts?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it only supports yuv420 in h264.

Comment: That's my impression as well. But I could not find good resources to confirm it. Do you know of codecs other that h264 that support transparency and works with iOS ?

Comment: ah, no - you have to roll your own transparency on ios. you can replace the player completely, or have a look at `AVVideoCompositionRenderContext` (I haven't tried the latter)

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to decode H264 into exactly 'RGBA' however:
a **AVPlayerItemVideoOutput** can be set to:**kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA** using the **kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey**

and

**VTDecompressionSessionCreate** also allows : **kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA**.

Then when rendering I swizzle the pixels like this: `gl_FragColor.bgra = texture2D(SamplerRGB, v_textureCoordinate);`

So the answer is yes but you have to do the rendering and swizzle.

/A

**(Edit. added links to code):**

Here is a really great project by Apple that will get you going.. [Real-time Video Processing Using AVPlayerItemVideoOutput](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVBasicVideoOutput/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013109-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

Just change it from YUV to RGB and bypass the 'colorConversionMatrix' part of the shader.

Good luck!

Comment: That sounds great. Can you share some code with how you set up the player / output and pass it to the shader?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'll have a look and try to get it work